# How to combine SVM and KNN?

Tags: python, svm, knn

This is SVM code

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC 
import joblib
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

data=np.load('data.npy')
target=np.load('target.npy')

train_data,test_data,train_target,test_target=train_test_split(data,target,test_size=0.2)
model=SVC()
model=SVC(kernel='poly')
model.fit(train_data,train_target)
model.kernel

predicted_target=model.predict(test_data) 

acc=accuracy_score(test_target,predicted_target)
print('Accuracy:',acc)
```

This is KNN code

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import joblib

data=np.load('data.npy')
target=np.load('target.npy')

print(data.shape)
print(target.shape,target)

train_data,test_data,train_target,test_target=train_test_split(data,target,test_size=0.2)
print(train_data.shape,train_target.shape)
print(test_data.shape,test_target.shape)

model=KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=30)
model.fit(train_data,train_target)

predicted_target=model.predict(test_data) 
print(predicted_target)

print(test_target)

acc=accuracy_score(test_target,predicted_target)
print('Accuracy:',acc)
```

I need to combine SVM and knn
How to combine SVM with KNN?
How to combine SVM with KNN
a) Train a support vector machine on the collection of nearest neighbors
b) Kernel function is defined as:

```
K(x,y) = <(x),(y)>
Distance function is converted to kernel function
K(x,y) = <x,y>
=1/2(<x,x> +<y,y> -<x-y, x-y >)
= ½(d(x,0) + d(y,0) – d(x,y))
```

How can I apply this algorithm to this code?

Comment: Do you only want to use the distance function as SVM's kernel function? so what's the usage of KNN here?

Comment: I want to combine SVM and KNN. when finding that I found this in a research paper. I don't know a way of combining SVM and KNN. if u know can u please help me thank you

Comment: Can you share the paper?

Comment: http://csjournals.com/IJCSC/PDF4-2/4.pdf - this is the paper.

Comment: I am new to machine learning thank you